# Android SHA 1 certificate

Tags: android, certificate, sha1, fingerprint

I using Google+ Auth API, and registered own application in developers console, where leave release SHA1 fingerprints.

When I build release apk and install on device, API works fine, but when I upload app on Play Market, API doesn't work and say that something is wrong with SHA1.

Comment: post logcat or the error please

Comment: did you generate release sha1?

Comment: @jagapathi Yes, keytool -exportcert myReleaseKeystorePath -list -v and check sha-1 with gradle -> MyProject ->Tasks -> android -> signing report

Comment: @quicklearner I can't post log, 'cause can't debug downloaded app from play market. This problem appears only if use version from play market. But I'm sure that the problem with sha

Comment: @jagapathi more details please)

Comment: @DenisMakovsky Please add the keytool command in the question (just edit it), it's better than putting in the comments.